# How to get entries that always have a certain value in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table "Test_Results" that looks like the following one:

Test_Results

```
|ID|Test_Name  |Status |
|0 | test_1    |passed |
|1 | test_2    |failed |
|2 | test_3    |skipped|
|3 | test_4    |passed |
|4 | test_5    |passed |
|5 | test_1    |passed |
|6 | test_2    |failed |
|7 | test_3    |passed |
|8 | test_4    |failed |
|9 | test_5    |passed |
|10| test_1    |passed |
|11| test_2    |failed |
|12| test_3    |passed |
|13| test_4    |passed |
|14| test_5    |passed |
```

The important thing is that test_2 always have status "failed" and test_5 have always status "passed".

So my question is how to retrive test_names that have always a certain status? For example, get the tests that have been always failing.

So far I have only come up with building objects in Java.
But have no idea how to write such MySQL query.

Thanks.

Comment: Make a sql fiddle. you should be able to do something like select test_name,status from test_results where status ='failed' group by test_name,status

Comment: Read an SQL tutorial first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For getting tests that have always been failed you could use this syntax:

```
SELECT Test_Name
FROM Test_Results
GROUP BY Test_Name
HAVING
  MAX(Status)='Failed'
  AND MIN(Status)='Failed'
```

to get tests that have an unique status (failed or passed) you could use this query:

```
SELECT Test_Name, MAX(Status) AS Status
FROM Test_Results
GROUP BY Test_Name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Status)=1
```